# How do I store different arrays from an array in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, append

I have a problem where I cant store different arrays in a list. I've got an array `displacement = [[0],[0],[0],[1],[5.5],[-7],[0],[0],[0]]` and I want to break it into *n* arrays with six rows and one column and then store the different arrays in a list.

I tried this:

```
    element_count = 2
    displacement = [[0],[0],[0],[1],[5.5],[-7],[0],[0],[0]]

    displacement_each_element = [] #empty list to store the arrays
    displacement_ele = np.ndarray((6, 1)) #numpy array

    for i in range(element_count):
        displacement_ele[0] = displacement[(i + 1) * 6 - i * 3 - 6]
        displacement_ele[1] = displacement[(i + 1) * 6 - i * 3 - 5]
        displacement_ele[2] = displacement[(i + 1) * 6 - i * 3 - 4]
        displacement_ele[3] = displacement[(i + 1) * 6 - i * 3 - 3]
        displacement_ele[4] = displacement[(i + 1) * 6 - i * 3 - 2]
        displacement_ele[5] = displacement[(i + 1) * 6 - i * 3 - 1]


        displacement_each_element.append(displacement_ele)
```

But when I do it like this the first "displacement_ele" array gets overwritten with the second one and the result is a list with two times the second "displacement_ele" array.

What should I do to not overwrite the first "displacement_ele" array?

The result should look like this, for this example:

```
displacement_each_element = [[[0],[0],[0],[1],[5.5],[-7]], [[1],[5.5],[-7],[0],[0],[0]]]
```

Comment: Sample output would help.

Comment: Move the line `displacement_ele = np.ndarray((6, 1))` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: You are saving the same array object to the list each time.  List append saves a reference, not a copy or fresh value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to partition 'displacement' into 'element_count' elements of 'num_columns' (6 in your case) columns. Such that you populate each element in order from your 'displacement' array. (I assumed that if you want more elements with more columns than 'displacement' allows, you just butt up against the end of 'displacement', getting repeats).
In my opinion, you can simplify your logic for indexing the 'displacement' array. Additionally, if you do, you can add logic to check for the edge case that is 'butting up against' the end of the 'displacement' array.
You basically assume that everything is in-order unless you butt up against the end of 'displacement', in which case you just populate your further 'displacement_ele's from the back of 'displacement'.

```
import numpy as np

element_count = 2
num_columns = 6
displacement = [[0],[0],[0],[1],[5.5],[-7],[0],[0],[0]]

displacement_each_element = [] #empty list to store the arrays
displacement_ele = np.ndarray((num_columns, 1)) #numpy array

for i in range(element_count):
    for j in range(num_columns):
        if (i*num_columns)+num_columns < len(displacement):  # check that you're not extending past the size of displacement
            # business as usual if your element_count and num_columns fits nicely within the displacement array
            displacement_ele[j] = displacement[(i*num_columns)+j]
        else:
            # this is the edge case where you hit the end of the array but still need another (or more, albeit they'll be repeated) displacement_ele's
            displacement_ele[j] = displacement[(-num_columns)+j]  
    displacement_each_element.append(displacement_ele)
    displacement_ele = np.ndarray((num_columns,1))

print(displacement_each_element)
```